# MVC4: How to delete view render cache?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

Im using Virtual Path Provider to store my view in database. The problem i have is that whenever i change the view code from my database, my rendering code always produces the view that is saved when the application started. So the problem i have now is that i have to keep restarting my application in order to change my view. Here is my rendering code:

```
    public static string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewToRender, object model, string controllerName, string loadAction, HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        string view = "";

        ViewDataDictionary ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model);
        Type controllerType = Type.GetType("CMS.Controllers." + controllerName + "Controller");
        object controller = Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType);
        RouteData rd = new System.Web.Routing.RouteData();
        rd.Values.Add("controller", controllerName);
        ((ControllerBase)(controller)).ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(httpContext, rd, (ControllerBase)controller);
        ControllerContext cc = ((ControllerBase)(controller)).ControllerContext;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(cc, viewToRender);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(cc, viewResult.View, ViewData, cc.Controller.TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(cc, viewResult.View);
            view = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }

        return view;
    }
```

the `ViewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw)` always renders the cached view. So how to delete the cache whenever i edited the view code?